# How do I get the building housenumber from OSM data?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, labeling

I've made a map in which buildings in a city are displayed using shapefiles from Geofabrik and unfortunately, none of the shapes contain the `housenumber`.

When I download the `.osm` files from Geofabrik the multipolygon layer is empty, but when I download the OSM Data directly via the OSM download tool in QGIS, the multipolygon layer contains buildings, but only if the area where I download it is very small (roughly 30 buildings at a time).

Is there a way to get the multipolygons from OSM other then downloading 30 buildings at a time, then when those are downloaded, extract the `housenumber` from the `other_tags` field in the attribute table?

Comment: I think you will need to create an extract from OSM Planet ( or other you like ) using osmosis. Try this: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:addr

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I'm trying to do it via an extract of planet.osm. But this will be very much work for me, so I only can start doing this in a view days/weeks.

Comment: Try it with a smaller import file. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Export

Comment: well, the problem is not the time of rendering, its the time i have to invest to understandy which syntax I have to use/create

Comment: or perhaps somebody knows the syntax off the cuff. I Need all buildings within Germany, with "name" and "housenumber" in the attribute table.

Comment: You can use the default style ( https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/default.style ) with `osm2pgsql`. It already have `addr:housenumber`. You can try a `select count("addr:housenumber") from planet_osm_polygon` after import. Also you can try same query in `planet_osm_point` to see what you've got. Concerning the `Germany`, you must have a Germany geometry to bound all your query results inside its territory (http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html).

Comment: The Germany map: http://www.statsilk.com/maps/download-free-shapefile-maps

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question. Upto now I do have everything in my qgis map (as shape files, with different styles per shape file). I thought I can somhow export the building-shapes including the housnumbers from an .osm file. I think I have misunderstood something.

Comment: From what I read now, I can't use the *.style file with qgis because its only readable in ArcGIS?

Comment: You're right. The `*.style` file is used in `osm2pgsql` to filter tags. The OSM file have a lot of information that may be not useful to you and will make your database huge. You can import from the OSM file to the database just what you need by filtering the the tags. Go here to see what you realy need http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features and edit `default.style`. The file extention does not help very much because it is not a CSS or SLD or XML styling file, but just a filter file to help import task.

Comment: Each `Key` will be a column in one or more `planet_osm_*` table and each `value` will become a line or tuple in that table. So if you put the `addr:housenumber` tag in your style file, the `planet_osm_*` tables will have a `addr:housenumber` column with your values. You must create a separate table filtering your data becaus the `planet_osm_*` tables have a lot of null columns because not all columns makes sense to the other column (`aerialway` don't have house number, for example). You must normalize the data by yourself.

Comment: No question is stupid here. Its a learning place. I'm glad to help. Your question is concerning at data level and all my answers is at there. If you need to make your map more attractive by stylizing you must create other question. As I said, the `style` name of the `osm2pgsql` importer is confusing. Is not a style file, but a data filter file.

Comment: `I thought I can somhow export the building-shapes including the housnumbers from an .osm file.` : You can `import` from the OSM file. Its what I'm telling you. Grab your OSM file, edit the `default.style` to have just what you realy need and do the import to the PostgreSQL. You will have the `planet_osm_*` with your data. Create separated tables by filtering data from that tables. Include the Germany geom in the data selection to get only Germany data. Done.

Comment: no I fail doing thsi guide to use Postgresql: http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_tut01 I think this stuff is a bit to high for me :(

Answer (score 3):

The OpenStreetMap Wiki is your friend: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features. You can also get a lot of good information from here: https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/addr:housenumber#combinations.

You may need this:

http://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osmosis/

and this: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:addr

This command line was not tested but can show the way:

`osmosis --read-xml your_osm_file.osm.bz2 --tag-filter accept-nodes addr:housenumber=*, addr:street=*, other_tags_you_may_need --write-xml roads.osm`

Or you can import to PostgreSQL using osm2pgsql: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql and use a custom `style` file: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/default.style

Osm2pgsql is simple to use but you must know how to do a good tunning or it will take a century to import your data.

`osm2pgsql -C 2500 -c -d database_target_table -U postgre_user -W -s -S ./your_style_file.style your_osm_file.osm`

[image]

**EDIT: Creating a table to make the things easy.**
This will be necessary when you need to create a Geoserver Layer.

Pros: Will be easy to locate just what you need.

Cons: You will duplicate the data and will be hard to update later (want to use a view?).

In this example I'll create a table `route-tunnels` from `planet_osm_line` with all tunnels. You just need to search for your data in `addr:housenumber` column at `planet_osm_line` table. Remember: As far as I know, not all streets will have house numbers. I think it will be in `planet_osm_polygon` table if you import `building:*` too.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "route-tunnels";
CREATE TABLE "route-tunnels" AS ( 
  SELECT way,highway FROM planet_osm_line 
  WHERE highway IN
  ( 'motorway', 'motorway_link', 'trunk', 'trunk_link', 
    'primary', 'primary_link', 'secondary', 'secondary_link',
    'tertiary', 'tertiary_link', 'residential', 'unclassified' )
  AND tunnel IN ( 'yes', 'true', '1' )
ORDER BY z_order );
CREATE INDEX "route-tunnels_way_idx" ON "route-tunnels" USING gist (way);
```

[image]
https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/building#combinations

Comment: thanks so far, I now installed osmosis, it works. But I can't find a guide, how to extract the house number. I can (with your command line) extract the buildings which do have a housenumber, but I do need a file with all buildings and a attribute "housenumber" where the housenumber ist stored, if there is one.

Comment: I've made a test importing all Key:Addr tags. AFAIK you can't rely all data will contain the house numbers. You must import the osmosis result to PostgreSQL or by using osm2pgsql. In this case osmosis will act as a pre filter. I like to go hard and don't use osmosis. I create a custom `style` file with all tags I want and do the import. So far you will need to create a table with your data (see my edit) by filtering `planet_osm_line` table.

Comment: But.... I'm afraid you can find the house numbers in `planet_osm_polygon` table because of the image above. It came from the OSM wiki and show house numbers to `buildings` and  the `buildings` are in `planet_osm_polygon`  because they are `areas (polygons)`. You will need to test it or wait some other user confirm it here ( @Iant ? ). Don't forget to import `building:*` too.

Comment: Keep in mind that housenumbers can be placed as single nodes inside the building polygons as well. So you have to look into `planet_osm_point` as well to get all available numbers.

Comment: @AndreJ agree. See the distribution percents here: https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/addr%3Ahousenumber

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using the full planet, you can download extracts in osm.pbf format from Geofabrik for certain regions. They contain all data within the region, while the shapefiles only contain some most-wanted topics.

You can load the data into a Postgis database with osm2pgsql, or in a spatialite database with ogr2ogr.

For use in QGIS, you can also try the QuickOSM plugin, which lets you download filtered topics from the OSM database inside the current view.

Keep in mind that housenumbers do not have to be tagged on a building, but sometimes only on a single node for the the entrance, or a shop (or several) that is inside the building.

In some cases, a building on a street corner may have different housenumbers for the entrances on the joining streets. These housenumbers can not be put on the building polygon in an easy way.

Comment: I've made some imports using osm2pgsql and play a little with the style file but I was unable to have much more house numbers. All I've got was some churches and commercial buildings and a few commom people houses. Can you show some tag combination to use as style file to get all possible house numbers?

Comment: The `addr:housenumber` tag is good enough, without a need to look for combinations. I usually take the centroid of the polygons, and add those to the `planet_osm_point` numbers in a new table. The other way round is much more complicated.