# How to download all addresses of some area from openstreet maps?

Tags: openstreetmap, csv, address

I need to know how to download all addresses of some area from openstreet maps?
After that I want to place all addresses in csv file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while looking for OSM download functions, I once came across the "overpass-turbo" tool (see http://overpass-turbo.eu/).
Although it requires quite some time to get into it and all necessary query commands, it might do what you need.

Please refer also to the according wiki: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL

You can find examples for a "CSV output mode" for a specified area.

A similar helpful discussion can be found here:
[How do I get the building housenumber from OSM data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198848/how-do-i-get-the-building-housenumber-from-osm-data)