# Select area in Maps and get List of all Addresses

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, google-maps, maps, list

I am looking for a way to select a residential subdivision online maps and get a list of all addresses in that selection.  What do you think?

[image]

I think this thread might lead in the direction of what I need [How do I get the building housenumber from OSM data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198848/how-do-i-get-the-building-housenumber-from-osm-data)

Comment: @jay84and welcome to GIS.Stackexchange, if you want to get an answer to your question I suggest you follow https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for edit recomendation